# Why automatic Atteched "\\" in String Using POST method with Params in Retrofit?

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

Hello i using Post method in retrofit . I have one Activity ProfileActivity and I try to update ProfileActivity. When i try to update my Activity it response like :-

```
"name": "\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"JohndoeOperator\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\"",
```

> I try to remove this extra "\"\" from my String ,But question is why
>   this add when i try to update my profile

Here is my code:-

APIInterface.java

```
@Multipart
@POST("updateProfile")
Call<UpdateProfileUserSideResponse> updateProfile(@Part("userId") int userId,
                                                  @Part("name") String name,
                                                  @Part("companyName") String companyName,
                                                  @Part("gstin") String gstin,
                                                  @Part("address") String address,
                                                  @Part("landmark") String landmark,
                                                  @Part("city") String city,
                                                  @Part("state") String state,
                                                  @Part("pincode") String pincode,
                                                  @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

and Here is my API call :-

```
final ApiInterface api = ApiClient.getApiService();
    Call<UpdateProfileUserSideResponse> call = api.updateProfile(preferenceManager.getUserId(), edt_user_FullName.getText().toString(), "", "", edt_user_address.getText().toString(), edt_user_landMark.getText().toString(), edt_user_city.getText().toString(), edt_user_state.getText().toString(), edt_user_pincode.getText().toString(), fileToUpload);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateProfileUserSideResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UpdateProfileUserSideResponse> call, Response<UpdateProfileUserSideResponse> response) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            preferenceManager.setName(response.body().getData().getName());
            Log.e("AHHHHHHAHAAA", "" + response.body().getData().getName());
            preferenceManager.setAddress(response.body().getData().getAddress());
            preferenceManager.setLandmark(response.body().getData().getLandmark());
            preferenceManager.setCity(response.body().getData().getCity());
            preferenceManager.setState(response.body().getData().getState());
            preferenceManager.setPincode(response.body().getData().getPincode());
            preferenceManager.setImage(response.body().getData().getImage());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UpdateProfileUserSideResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `Log.e("AHHHHHHAHAAA",` i sense frustration :P

Comment: could you please post where you are creating that api request ?

Comment: I think it is the matter of your REST code. It's using backslash to avoid interpreting quotation mark  as a meta-character. If you have access to the rest api wrap your post with htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 0):

First, check your API on [postman plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop//%40) of chrome browser

Is gives the same result on postman as well.